# How to compare between two dataframes pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df1 like below and i want check if all the values of certain column in df2 are between df1 max and min value. If it is i want to give value from name column of that index. If df2 value is not in between any of those , i want to see if it is bigger or smaller than any of df1 max or min value.

```
data = {'Name':  ['MN1', 'MN2', 'MN3', 'MN4', 'MN5', 'MN6', 'MN7-8', 'MN9', 'MN10', 'MN11', 'MN12', 'MN13', 'MN14', 'MN15', 'MN16','MN17', 'MQ18', 'MQ19'],
        'MAX': [23, 21.7, 19.5, 17.2, 16.4, 14.2, 12.85, 11.2, 9.9, 8.9, 7.6, 7.1, 5.3, 5, 3.55, 2.5, 1.9, 0.85],
         'MIN':[21.7, 19.5, 17.2, 16.4, 14.2, 12.85, 11.2, 9.9, 8.9, 7.6, 7.1, 5.3, 5, 3.55, 2.5, 1.9, 0.85, 0.01]
        }
df1 = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Name','MAX','MIN'])
```

I tried this:

```
list = []

for i in df2['AVERAGE_AGE']:
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        if row['MAX'] >= i and row['MIN'] < i:
            list.append(row['Name'])
    
    if i > df1['MAX'].max():
        list.append("Postmn")
    elif i < df1['MIN'].min():
        list.append("Premn")
    
df2['MNname'] = list
```

this takes long time and list length doesn't match with length of df2

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
(df2['AVERAGE_AGE'] < df1['MIN'].min()).value_counts()
(df2['AVERAGE_AGE'] > df1['MAX'].max()).value_counts()
```

This will tell you the number of rows that satisfy the conditions by giving the counts of True and False.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the first dataframe and set Names for the second using [pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([
...   2.299367, 20.688943, 10.245027, 1.412258, 22.541987,
...   2.588420, 5.578598, 11.703629, 12.529066, 17.769196,
...   ], columns=['AVERAGE_AGE'])
>>> for index, row in df1.iterrows():
...   df2.loc[(df2.AVERAGE_AGE>=row.MIN) & (df2.AVERAGE_AGE<row.MAX),'Name'] = row.Name
... 
>>> df2
   AVERAGE_AGE   Name
0     2.299367   MN17
1    20.688943    MN2
2    10.245027    MN9
3     1.412258   MQ18
4    22.541987    MN1
5     2.588420   MN16
6     5.578598   MN13
7    11.703629  MN7-8
8    12.529066  MN7-8
9    17.769196    MN3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arr = []
for i in range(df2.shape[0]):    
    # Check if the value in COLUMN_1 is between MIN and MAX value
    if ((df2['COLUMN_1'][i] > df1['MIN'][i]) and df2['COLUMN_1'][i] < df1['MAX'][i]):
        arr.append(df1['Name'][i])
    # Check if value in COLUMN_1 is less than Minimum value
    elif (df2['COLUMN_1'][i] < df1['MIN'][i]):
        arr.append(np.round(df2['COLUMN_1'][i] - df1['MIN'][i], 2))
    # Check if value in COLUMN_1 is less than Minimum value
    elif (df2['COLUMN_1'][i] > df1['MAX'][i]):
        arr.append(np.round(df2['COLUMN_1'][i] - df1['MAX'][i], 2))

df2['Name'] = pd.Series(arr)
```

As you have not mentioned exactly the name of column to be checked in df2, I have used it as COLUMN_1. The conditions and values used are:

1. If the value in COLUMN_1 is between MIN and MAX then get data corresponding to df1['Name']
2. If the value in COLUMN_1 is less than MIN then do (value in COLUMN_1 - MIN) giving negative value
3. If the value in COLUMN_1 is greater than MAX then do (value in COLUMN_1 - MAX) giving positive value

Hope this works!